# Tips for saving memory when coding under android?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

Im currently developing a software under android and im getting quite quickly some OutOfMemoryException.... I did modified some part of my code to use more static variables instead of making new allocation with the "new" operator but is there any things else to do ? or any other tips ? Any advices would be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a lot of tips here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html

Especially look at the **Avoid Creating Objects** topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can also watch some Google I/O conferences, like the ones about [writing non-janky apps](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-CH/events/io/2010/sessions/writing-zippy-android-apps.html) or [how to make fast and efficient apps](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-CH/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) from 2009.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some resources that can be reloaded onto memory anytime, consider using `WeakReference`s. The objects inside them will be cleared just before the (Java) VM throws OutOfMemoryException, so there will be some more memory available.

Answer (score 1):

You may be accessing too many resources (such as images) before garbage collector can handle/recycle them. If you're accessing particularly large images, then use BitmapFactory to scale them down, as seen [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966) on SO. (Of course, for this you would see something like "bitmap size exceeds vm budget" in your logcat too.) 
Any more details on the error?

Comment: Well, im loading a bunch of small images in a function. But if I call several time this function, it will run out of memory. Its doesnt look so much to clean everything in between the difference time call. I have worked on my code to use more static variables but i saw in some case you cannot use them, especially when dealing with adapter or view objects...

Comment: You can try manual garbage collection when you don't need that particular bitmap. Code is bitmap.recycle(). I have not tried it but have seen it referenced here many times.